# How can i group table into months

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

A `IGrouping<'a, Order>.Key { get; }`
Gets the key of the `IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>`.
Returns:
The key of the `IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>`.
Types:
a is `new { int Month }`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'

This is what i tried...

```cs
public class Order {
    public DateTimeOffset OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTimeOffset Month { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrderService
{
    IEnumerable<Order> GetDataAsync();
}

public class OrderService : RepositoryBase<Order>,IOrderService
{
    public OrderService(RepositoryContext repositoryContext) : base(repositoryContext)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Order> GetDataAsync()
    {
        return FindAll().OrderBy(ow => ow.OrderDate)
            .GroupBy(o => new
            { 
                   Month = o.OrderDate.Month
            })
            .Select(g => new MyViewModel
            {
                Month = g.Key.Month,// error is here
                Subtotal =g.Sum(x => x.Subtotal)
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my database
order:

```
[
  {"OrderDate": "2023-01-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal": 100},
  {"OrderDate": "2023-01-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal": 100},
  {"OrderDate": "2023-01-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal": 100},
  {"OrderDate": "2023-02-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal": 200},
  {"OrderDate": "2023-02-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal":200},
  {"OrderDate": "2023-03-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal": 400},
  {"OrderDate": "2023-04-08 20:07:31.0002873", "Subtotal":700}
]
```

Here is what am expecting

```
[
  {"Month": "January", "Subtotal": 300}
  {"Month": "February", "Subtotal": 400}
  {"Month": "March", "Subtotal": 400}
  {"Month": "April", "Subtotal": 700}
]
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.month?view=net-7.0), `DateTimeOffset.Month` is of data type `int`. `MyViewModel`'s property `Month` has data type `DateTimeOffset`. I am suspecting you actually want to change the data type of `MyViewModel.Month` from `DateTimeOffset` to `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by  using the following code

```
 var _dds = context.Orders.OrderBy(ow => ow.OrderDate)
          .GroupBy(o => new
          {
              Year = o.OrderDate.Year,
              Month = o.OrderDate.Month

          })
          .Select(g => new MyViewModel
          {
              Month = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Parse(g.Key.Year + "-" + g.Key.Month + "-01")),
              Subtotal = g.Sum(x => x.Subtotal)
          })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was accurate and straight forward.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use a DateTimeOffset to store only the month as string in the viewmodel.

why not juste use a string directly for month in your viewmodel ?

if you realy need to have a DateTimeOffset use g.First(), it will give you the first item for the current key

Answer (score 0):

`o.OrderDate.Month` is an `int`. Also note that grouping only by the month number is problematic if the dates span more than one year. I would group by year and month. From this, you can then create a new `DateTimeOffset`.

Another problem is the `Offset`. Is the source date also of type `DateTimeOffset`? If yes you can take this offset from there. This requires grouping by this offset as well. Otherwise you will have to specify a constant offset as a `TimeSpan`.

```cs
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> GetDataAsync()
{
    return FindAll()
        .GroupBy(o => new
            {
                Year = o.OrderDate.Year,
                Month = o.OrderDate.Month,
                Offset = o.OrderDate.Offset
            })
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Year)
        .ThenBy(g => g.Key.Month)
        .Select(g => new MyViewModel
            {
                Month = new DateTimeOffset(
                    g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, g.Key.Offset),
                Subtotal = g.Sum(x => x.Subtotal)
            })
        .ToList();
}
```

I have set `day` to 1 and `hour`, `minute` and `second` to `0`. Note that it is more efficient to order the grouped data containing less records.

It may also be okay not to group by the offset and then to take one with `g.First(x => x.OrderDate.Offset)`

Comment: Thanks, the date is saved as DateTimeOffset... and your solution gives this error, Non-invocable member 'DateTimeOffset' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: I added the `new` keyword before `DateTimeOffset` in an edit.

Comment: Now i got a new error, we are winning... "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Repository.Data.MyViewModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Entities.OrderAggregate.Order>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Okay I have not tried this code, but the fix is to Order before Select. (see my edited version).

Comment: It gives the same error. do i have to change the month data type to string from MyViewModel?

Comment: Ohh, now I see it. The method is typed `IEnumerable<Order> GetDataAsync()` instead of `IEnumerable<MyViewModel> GetDataAsync()`. Because, obviously you are returning a List of MyViewModels.